How do I use environment-specific vars / secrets in GitHub Actions instead of the repository level?
I have set up environment-specific variables & secrets (not on a repository level):

In my YAML file, I set it up like below as referenced to this answer:
    name: Run k6 tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: dev # environment named in Github action settings
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Run tests
        uses: grafana/k6-action@v0.3.1
        with:
          filename: tests/api/login.spec.js
        env:
          BASE_URL: ${{ env.BASE_URL }}
          USERNAME: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}

However, when I run the pipeline, it all shows blank:

I tried using it on a repository level and works fine but my variables would change per environment so I would the pipeline to be more flexible.

use vars.BASE_URL instead of env, also if it is a secret it wont show it
